# "Multi-tasking" on Gantt chart in ChartDirectory for Python

Tags: python, charts

I'm  generating gantt charts for representing the machine ocupation of a production line of a furniture factory. It has several machines and the machines working in parallel, full time (or almost it).

I found this library ([Chart-Director](http://www.advsofteng.com/index.html)) for Python and successfully installed and ran a sample code.

```
# data for the gantt chart, representing the start date, end date and names for
# various activities
startDate = [chartTime(2004, 8, 16), chartTime(2004, 8, 30), chartTime(2004, 9, 13),
    chartTime(2004, 9, 20), chartTime(2004, 9, 27), chartTime(2004, 10, 4),
    chartTime(2004, 10, 25), chartTime(2004, 11, 1), chartTime(2004, 11, 8)]
endDate = [chartTime(2004, 8, 30), chartTime(2004, 9, 13), chartTime(2004, 9, 27),
    chartTime(2004, 10, 4), chartTime(2004, 10, 11), chartTime(2004, 11, 8),
    chartTime(2004, 11, 8), chartTime(2004, 11, 22), chartTime(2004, 11, 22)]
labels = []
for i in range(0,9):
    labels.append("Maq" + str(i))

# Create a XYChart object of size 620 x 280 pixels. Set background color to light
# blue (ccccff), with 1 pixel 3D border effect.
c = XYChart(1080, 640, 0xccccff, 0x000000, 1)

# Add a title to the chart using 15 points Times Bold Itatic font, with white
# (ffffff) text on a deep blue (000080) background
c.addTitle("Simple Gantt Chart Demo", "timesbi.ttf", 15, 0xffffff).setBackground(
    0x000080)

# Set the plotarea at (140, 55) and of size 460 x 200 pixels. Use alternative
# white/grey background. Enable both horizontal and vertical grids by setting their
# colors to grey (c0c0c0). Set vertical major grid (represents month boundaries) 2
# pixels in width
c.setPlotArea(140, 55, 900, 500, 0xffffff, 0xeeeeee, LineColor, 0xc0c0c0, 0xc0c0c0
    ).setGridWidth(2, 1, 1, 1)

# swap the x and y axes to create a horziontal box-whisker chart
c.swapXY()

# Set the y-axis scale to be date scale from Aug 16, 2004 to Nov 22, 2004, with ticks
# every 7 days (1 week)
c.yAxis().setDateScale(chartTime(2004, 8, 16), chartTime(2004, 11, 22), 3600)

# Set multi-style axis label formatting. Month labels are in Arial Bold font in "mmm
# d" format. Weekly labels just show the day of month and use minor tick (by using
# '-' as first character of format string).
c.yAxis().setMultiFormat(StartOfMonthFilter(), "<*font=arialbd.ttf*>{value|mmm d}",
    StartOfDayFilter(), "-{value|d}")

# Set the y-axis to shown on the top (right + swapXY = top)
c.setYAxisOnRight()

# Set the labels on the x axis
c.xAxis().setLabels(labels)

# Reverse the x-axis scale so that it points downwards.
# c.xAxis().setReverse()

# Set the horizontal ticks and grid lines to be between the bars
c.xAxis().setTickOffset(0.5)

# Add a green (33ff33) box-whisker layer showing the box only.
c.addBoxWhiskerLayer(startDate, endDate, None, None, None, 0x00cc00, SameAsMainColor,
    SameAsMainColor)

# Output the chart
c.makeChart("gantt.png")
```

This code outputs the current image:
[image]

This way, it is like each machine could be part of the process just once, but this is not the case. In other words, I want to have every machine busy most of the time, so I need to draw several "block" per "row", but I can't find a way of doing it.

I already tried to create `startDate` as a list of a list of dates, but I get an execution error:

```
startDate = [[chartTime(2004, 8, 16), chartTime(2004, 8, 30)], chartTime(2004, 9, 13), ...
```

I digged a little bit more and found that is possible to create multi-layer charts:
http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdpython.htm#layergantt.htm

But doing this way will be very complicated to know when I need to add another layer.

Is there any easier way of doing? Is there any other library that will allow me to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this a company based answer, but have you already tried VARCHART XGantt (http://www.netronic.com/products/varchart-xgantt/overview.html)?
It is very flexible and can do what you need.

Comment: this is not in python programming,that's only suggest a tools.